# Issue with return pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to duplicate a copy of the array but the new copy needs to be in reverse order. My  problem is my `reverse` function, I commented what the error is stating, what I don't understand is why it's stating that? If copy is a pointer variable? I'm still struggling with pointers, and I really just want some clarification on what I am doing wrong. I didn't make a reverse pointer variable yet, I was planning to do that once I figure out why I'm given this error.

Here's the function

```
int* reverse(int elements, int size)
{
    int* copy = new int [size];
    int k =0;
    for(int j=size-1; j >=0;j--)
    {
        copy[k] = size[j]; // Error-> Subscripted value is not an array,pointer or vector
        k++;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Here's the entire code without the function,

```
#include <iostream>

int* allocation(int);
void output(int*, int);
int* reverse(int*, int);

int main()
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "Enter the size you want to allocate" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> size;
    int* array = allocation(size);
    std::cout << "Displays the elements of the array";
    output(array,size);
    return 0;
}

void output(int* array, int size)
{
    for(int k=0;k<size;k++)
    {
        std::cout << " " << array[k];
    }
}

int* allocation(int elements)
{
    int* ptr = new int[elements];
    std::cout << "Enter the elements for size of array." << std::endl;
    for(int i =0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        std:: cin >> ptr[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `reverse` function is that you are not passing pointer to source array which has to be copied in the reverse order. Instead, you have passed two `int`s.

The error

> Error-> Subscripted value is not an array,pointer or vector

happens when you try to use `size` as an array by adding a subscript to it `size[j]` which is obvious because `size` is an `int` type and not a pointer, array or a vector

I have changed the signature of your function from

```
int* reverse(int elements, int size)
```

to

```
int* reverse(int *elements, int size)
```

I have modified your function to look this way

```
int* reverse(int *elements, int size)
{
    int* copy = new int [size];
    for(int j=size-1, k=0; j >=0; j--, k++)
    {
        // copy from elements and not size, elements is the array containing 
        // the values to be copied, size denotes the size of the array
        copy[k] = elements[j];  
    }
    return copy;
}
```

**Side note:**

1. I have also put `k` in the scope of the for loop.
2. You may want to use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of using raw arrays
3. I see that you have used the correct signature while defining the function `int* reverse(int*, int);`

Comment: Thank you, it makes a lot of sense now.